# How to connect with AWS in ASP.NET Core web app in order to generate access token for making SDK calls?

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-sdk-net

I need to have an ability to allow a user to connect to his AWS account so that when he is redirected back to my ASP.NET core web application, I should receive an access token to make AWS SDK calls on his behalf.

How can this be achieved? Sample code would really help.

I was thinking to use an SSO integration like Auth0 but SSO is not really my requirement per se. A simple solution is what I am looking for.